# Django Rest Framework. Check difference between fields value for two POSTs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Dont know how to do this:
I have program, that create data with POST and have some fields, like:

```
create_data:
id:
value:
```

Need check field "value" between current and previous POST, and if previous "value" more then current "value" - prevent create current POST with error.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You question is too broad, it is not about python and Django at all. You should add some code and point in your problem.

Comment: At first i was created data like: create_data: 04.01.2017, value: 150 Before create next POST, need check that new POSTs field ''value'' will more then old value (150). And if its false - prevent create POST and call error ('Wrong value)

Answer (score 1):

You can save the POST data in a [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/).
So you can compare values between POSTS.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden

def a_view(request):
    last_post_value = request.session.get('value')
    current_post_value = request.POST.get('value')
    if last_post_value > current_post_value:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    request.session['value'] = current_post_value
    return HttpResponse()
```

You can use [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/) to save your data as well.

Comment: Next POST data can go in next session. So, how i can do it with models?

Comment: Models would be only a way to organize better your data and keep track of what happend, then you just save the model id of the last post in the session, and recover it in the next post.